# Is it possible to remove empty cells at the bottom of the table view via Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder, xcode6

Can I do the following action via Interface Builder in XCode?

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

I need to remove empty cells at the bottom of the table view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that can only be done in code. IB is missing a checkbox for Show Empty Cells.

May I ask why you don't want it in your code?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I prefer to do any things in the Interface Builder. Is it wrong?

Comment: Not really, I was just wondering. Actually I agree that it would be nice to be able to keep all interface-related settings in IB but alas a bunch of them are not available there.

Comment: Settings the table footer view (to an empty view) is possible in Interface Builder.  
See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27230157/1336645

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you only have to add an UIView to your tableview as a tableFooterView. With a general tableFooterView empty cells won't be displayed anymore.

In code as you stated :

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

In IB / Storyboard :

Simply drag an UIView inside your UITableView. If you can't place it directly after the Sections, then place it before the section (as a tableHeaderView) and then drag it after. It will be considered as the tableview's footer ;-)

[image]